# How to upgrade jquery 2.2.1 to 3.7.1

Tags: jquery

When I upgraded jquery from 2.2.1 to 3.7.1, all my script tag display block and jquery.isFunction and jquery.isArray is deprecated error in console.

How to resolve this display block issue and how to change code in Jquery.dform-1.1.0.min.js related to jQuery.isFunction() and jquery.isArray()

Comment: `deprecated` means: will be removed in a future version, but otherwise fully workable.   For `jquery.dform.min.js` you should contact your supplier / the author for an up-to-date version - if it's not been updated then at the minimum get the non-minimised/original version and make the changes yourself.

Comment: It looks like jquery-dform is no longer updated - so you would need to make the changes yourself:  github: https://github.com/daffl/jquery.dform

Comment: Thanks freedoms-m,Can you please suggest When I changed from a.isFunction(a.fn.progressbar) to (typeof a.fn.progressbar === "function") in jquery.dform.min.js then getting error cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'progressbar'.

Comment: because `a.fn` in your code is undefined.   The `$.isFunction` doesn't check for null (at least in the version I have to hand, nor the version SO is using), so it's unclear why you weren't getting the same error with `a.isFunction(a.fn.progressbar)`

Answer (score 1):

`isFunction` is deprecated since jQuery 3.3, see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/

You can find and replace all calls to this function with

```
typeof yourParam === "function"
```

Recommendation: Search for all matches of **isFunction(** in your code and change it as instructed above. So, a code of `jQuery.isFunction(someparam)` would become `(typeof someparam === "function")`.

`isArray` is deprecated since jQuery 3.2 (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/)

In order to fix this, change

```
jQuery.isArray(someparam)
```

to

```
Array.isArray(someparam)
```

Example:

```js
let foo = function() {};
let bar = [];

let obj = {foo, bar};

for (let key in obj) {
    console.log(`${key} is ${(typeof obj[key] === "function") ? "" : "not "} a function`)
    console.log(`${key} is ${Array.isArray(obj[key]) ? "" : "not "} an array`)
}
```

Comment: When I changed from a.isFunction(a.fn.progressbar) to (typeof a.fn.progressbar === "function") in jquery.dform.min.js then getting error cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'progressbar').

Comment: @Dimps that means that `a` is undefined.